# Why need to add columns in dimensionsSpec when creating Druid schema

Tags: druid

I tried to create my Druid schema, and I refereed a example as following:

```
{"dimensionsSpec": {"dimensions": ["timestamp”,"netname"] },
 "columns":  ["second_time","timestamp"],
 "delimiter": "/001"
}
```

My question is that, if I indicated dimensions, why should I indicate columns again.
Btw, should I put timestamp(it is seconds) in the dimension? since my granularity is MINUTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to specify columns attribute in your ingestion spec. dimensionSpec and metricsSpec are enough. here's the sample example of ingestion spec:

```
"dimensionsSpec" : {
    "dimensions": [
      "srcIP",
      { "name" : "srcPort", "type" : "long" },
      { "name" : "dstIP", "type" : "string" },
      { "name" : "dstPort", "type" : "long" },
      { "name" : "protocol", "type" : "string" }
    ]
  }
```

Druid has excellent documentation, here are good reference links about how to write ingestion spec:
[Writing Druid Ingestion Spec](http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-ingestion-spec.html),
[Imply Ingestion Spec Docs](https://docs.imply.io/on-prem/tutorial/ingestion-spec)

**Answer to your 2nd question:**

There is no need to include timestamp in dimension list. To specify granularity you can use granularitySpec. Here's the example:

```
"granularitySpec" : {
    "type" : "uniform",
    "segmentGranularity" : "HOUR",
    "queryGranularity" : "MINUTE"
    "rollup" : true
}
```

Note that there are two types of granularity you can specify here, segmentGranularity refers to what size of time interval should a single segment contain data for and queryGranularity is used while querying to druid table

Comment: thank you! if "columns" not needed, what's "columns" for? in which scenario we would use "columns"?

Comment: Can you please post a link for the example you are referring to?

Comment: sorry, it's an internal project(private project), and I just saw the old document showed the schema like that, but one one maintain it now.

Comment: For current ingestion spec, you don't need columns in your spec, so there will be no scenario when you will need "columns" in your ingestion spec